# Singleton timer throws timer exception

Tags: java, mysql, jboss, singleton

I am using singleton bean to read data from log file store it in Mysql DB,

`@Schedule(minute = "*/15", hour = "*", persistent = false) @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")`

if it reads single log file works fine but more than one file it throws below mentioned exception at the line of `ps = mycon.prepareStatement(Query)`

Exception appeared in server:

`2014-11-03 14:35:20,101 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-15-thread-1) org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: Transaction TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffc0a80ac1:126a:54572251:184 status: ActionStatus.ABORTED > cannot proceed STATUS_ROLLEDBACK; - nested throwable: (javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffc0a80ac1:126a:54572251:184 status: ActionStatus.ABORTED > cannot proceed STATUS_ROLLEDBACK)`

> 2014-11-03 14:35:20,102 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-15-thread-1)    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.checkTransactionActive(WrapperDataSource.java:165)
>
> 2014-11-03 14:35:20,102 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-15-thread-1)  at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkTransactionActive(WrappedConnection.java:843)
>
> 2014-11-03 14:35:20,103 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-15-thread-1)  at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkStatus(WrappedConnection.java:858)
>
> 2014-11-03 14:35:20,103 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-15-thread-1)  at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkTransaction(WrappedConnection.java:835)
>
> 2014-11-03 14:35:20,103 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-15-thread-1)  at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedConnection.prepareStatement(WrappedConnection.java:250)
>
> 2014-11-03 14:35:20,104 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-15-thread-1)  at com.pms.single.PmsLogInsert.avgRespTimeRead(PmsLogInsert.java:1058)
>
> 2014-11-03 14:35:20,104 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-15-thread-1)  at com.pms.single.PmsLogInsert.createIndex(PmsLogInsert.java:438)
>
> 2014-11-03 14:35:20,129 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-15-thread-1) Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffc0a80ac1:126a:54572251:184 status: ActionStatus.ABORTED > cannot proceed STATUS_ROLLEDBACK